# How to regularize when facing exchangeable vectors in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, matrix, regularization, exchangeability

I am seeking to estimate a regularization method to estimate the conditional probability $p(y|\mathbf{X})$ where $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R^{n\times m}}$ and where the probabilities are invariant by permutation column-wise on $\mathbf{X}$.

Formally,

- let $\mathbf{X}=(X_1, .., X_n)$
- let $\pi: [1 .. n] \to [1 .. n]$ be a permutation,
- let $\mathbf{X}_\pi=(X_{\pi(1)}, .., X_{\pi(n)})$

We have $p(y|\mathbf{X})=p(y|\mathbf{X}_\pi)$ and $p(\mathbf{X})=p(\mathbf{X}_\pi)$.

The [exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) of the vectors is a strong prior, and I am seeking a regularization method (maybe akin in spirit to covolutional networks) that structurally reflect this property of the problem.

A data augmentation scheme can be used, generating many extra examples by applying random column permutations on known examples; however, this feels like an extremely wasteful approach in terms of calculations.

Does anyone know how to regularize $p$ estimation in such a situation?

Comment: Remark: the property on $X$ you are referring to is known as [exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables). The assumption $p(y \vert X )=p(y \vert X_π)$ is automatically true if $X$ and $X_\pi$ have the same law, which is what you want to express with the second part of the assumption:  $p( X )=p(X_π)$, am I right?

Comment: Forget about second part, I wrote it too quickly... it is wrong without more assumptions. Take two r.v. independant $X$ and $Y$ with same law (say Gaussian) the law of $X$ knowing $X$ is degenerated while $X$ knowing $Y$ is the same Gaussian.

Comment: Thanks! I have just updated the question to reflect this proper terminology.

Comment: Perhaps pre-process inputs into a default permutation? (e.g. [lexicographical order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Cartesian_products))

Comment: Pre-process the inputs into a default permutation would be missing the regularization part. Exchangeability is a very strong prior, much stronger than translation invariance (used for convolutional networks). Thus, I am seeking a correspondingly strong regularization method that embeds this prior into the learning method.

Comment: Maybe first think about how this information can be built into your statistical model?  And tell us some more context to be able to help with that.